# restore snapshot from VirtualBox to a real machine

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, virtualization, snapshot, guest-os

I'm running a Virtual Box vm featuring Ubuntu 20.04. My host os is Ubuntu 22.04.
I'd like to *move* the guest os on a dual boot partition on my machine, possibly without losing any data about its current state (since there's a ton of stuff about ROS).

My question might be a little strange, but is it feasible to take a snapshot of the guest os running on Virtual Box and then restore it on a real machine with the same os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy method, and I have tested it only when moving a system from one bare-metal installation to another bare-metal installation, but I think there are no fundamental reasons why this shouldn't work between a VM and a bare-metal installation.

First you can try [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). You would need to boot your VM from a live Clonezilla image, then you would need to provide some target drive to Clonezilla to store the image (you would need to passthrough some partition - if you have a free one - or eg. external USB drive to be used by your VM). After you restore the Clonezilla image onto your target machine, it may need some adjustments, for example removing the VM-specific drivers if such were installed. Therefore I said it is not easy. You have to **know** what you are doing.

If Clonezilla fails, you can try to boot your VM from live Ubuntu image, `tar` the entire filesystem (or filesystems, if you have more than one) to an archive on the external drive. Then boot your target machine from live Ubuntu media, create partition(s) and make filesystem(s), then untar your tar file(s) onto the appropriate filesystem(s). Finally, again you will need some adjustments like putting the proper partition IDs into `/etc/fstab` and you need to install the bootloader on the target system.

It is not possible to go into details here, only give some hints, as you have to really understand what you're doing. Then the procedure is pretty straightforward (although not easy).

Comment: I have moved a VM to a hardware installation using the method you describe (Clonezilla). You do indeed have to remove some files to stop getting nuisance errors. There is an uninstall script in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions that helps.

Comment: @raj I think I might try your second option, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to migrate an OS from bare-metal to a VM, the reverse is not possible.  The reasons for this are many.
What you might be able to do is install an OS as dual-boot, then copy over the dotfiles.  I've not tried this myself, so YMMV.
If successful, this would migrate any customizations, but not the current machine state.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I have migrated a Virtualbox VM to a hardware machine successfully.